# Gridview image data from sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-gridview

I have a grid view with images, when I click an image I start a new activity. What I need now is that I have specific data (text,images) about the image in the grid view, I want them to retrieve them from Sqlite, i need directions what all can I do.

I can get the position of the clicked image by

```
intent.putExtra("Index", position);
```

how to get that image in the new intent and how to retrieve the row from sqlite

Comment: In your adapter, on the onClickListener, can't you get the src of the image using the view ? I guess you should get the path to your image, and put it in extra to your new intent.

Comment: you can retrieve a data from database in onCreate method with your new Activity..

Answer (score 0):

I hope I good understand what you want to do.

You can do this using caching images - it will be the fastest way.
([Caching images library - lazy list)](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Then you can put into new activity link into images (which is showing in gridview) and in new activity load that images.

Or if you want to use database - load images into database as table of int which you can get from bitmap (or just from ImageView)